# VBA: Add Carriage Return + Line Feed at the start of Uppercase phrase

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have cells that contain various information.
In these cells, there are multiple Uppercase phrases.

I would like to be able to split the contents of the cell by adding the CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) Carriage return - linefeed combination
to the start of each new Uppercase phrase.

The only consistency is that the multiple Uppercase phrases begin after a period (.) and before open parenthesis "("

**Example:**
 - Add CRLF to start of PERSUADER
 - Add CRLF to start of RIVER JEWEL
 - Add CRLF to start of TAHITIAN DANCER
 - Add CRLF to start of AMBLEVE
 - Add CRLF to start of GINA'S HOPE

NOTE:
There are multiple periods (.) in the text.
I have highlighted the text in red for a visual purpose only (normal text/font during import).
I am OK with either formula, UDF or VBA sub.

[image: Screenshot]

**TEXT**

> PERSUADER (1) won by a margin first up at Kyneton. Bit of authority about her performance there and with the stable finding form it's easy to see her going right on with that. Ran really well when placed at Caulfield second-up last prep and that rates well against these. RIVER JEWEL (2) has been racing well at big odds. I have to like the form lines that she brings back in class now. Shapes as a key danger. TAHITIAN DANCER (5) will run well. She was okay without a lot of room at Flemington last time. AMBLEVE (13) is winning and can measure up while GINA'S HOPE (11) wasn't too far from River Jewel at Flemington and ties in as a hope off that form line.

I was able to extract with this function - but not able to manipulate the data in the cell
This is my code so far:

```
Function UpperCaseWords(ByVal S As String) As String 
    Dim X As Long, Words() As String
    Const OkayPunctuation As String = ",."";:'&,-?!"

    For X = 1 To Len(OkayPunctuation)
        S = Replace(S, Mid(OkayPunctuation, X, 1), " ") 
    Next
    Words = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(S)) 
    For X = 0 To UBound(Words)
        If Words(X) Like "*[!A-Z]*" Then Words(X) = "" 
    Next 
    UpperCaseWords = Trim(Join(Words)) 
End Function
```

Comment: Nice question, however it's lacking the most important part, your own attempt with a description where you get stuck. Note that SO is not a free coding service. Btw, a perfect use case for regular expressions.

Comment: I was able to extract with this function - but not able to manipulate the data in the cell.  `Function UpperCaseWords(ByVal S As String) As String
  Dim X As Long, Words() As String
  Const OkayPunctuation As String = ",."";:'&,-?!"
  For X = 1 To Len(OkayPunctuation)
    S = Replace(S, Mid(OkayPunctuation, X, 1), " ")
  Next
  Words = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(S))
  For X = 0 To UBound(Words)
    If Words(X) Like "*[!A-Z]*" Then Words(X) = ""
  Next
  UpperCaseWords = Trim(Join(Words))
  
End Function`

Comment: You'd better update your original question for readibility =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is not the same as your examples.

- None of your examples start after a `dot`.
- Most start after a `dot-space` except

  - `PERSUADER` starts at the start of the string
  - `GINA'S HOPE` starts after a space

I incorporated those rules into a regular expression, but, since your *upper case words* can include punctuation, for brevity I just looked for
  - words that **excluded** lower case letters and digits
  - words at least three characters long

If that is not sufficient in your real data, the regex can easily be made more specific:

```
Option Explicit
Function upperCaseWords(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "^|\s(\b[^a-z0-9]+\b\s*\()"
    upperCaseWords = .Replace(S, vbCrLf & "$1")
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Was busy on a regex.replace myself. But this one looks so much cleaner already. Great job Ron.

Comment: Ron, this works perfectly. I cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

as per your wording

> The only consistency is that the multiple Uppercase phrases begin
>   after a period (.) and before open parenthesis "("

this should do:

```
Function UpperCaseWords(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim w As Variant
    Dim s1 As String

    For Each w In Split(s, ". ")
        If InStr(w, "(") Then w = Chr(13) + Chr(10) & w
        s1 = s1 & w
    Next
    UpperCaseWords = s1
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP accepted the formula solution, and here is a formula answer .

Assume data put in `A1`

In `B1`, enter formula and copied across until blank :

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" (. "&$A1," while ",". ")," (",REPT(" ",700)),COLUMN(A1)*700,700))&" ",". ",REPT(" ",300)),300))
```